# ¿Como enviar body y multiples imágenes a un api rest en ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, ionic, cordova

estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil con ionic, y tengo un array con fotos que el usuario hace con el movil o carga de la galería, así:

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imagePath =>  {
  this.imagen = imagePath;
  this.galeriaImg.push(this.imagen);
})
```

Ahora, quiero que cuando realizo el post al servidor (que es una api rest en nodejs), además de lo que le envío en el body, pueda pasarle ese array de imágenes en la misma petición.
He estado mirando como hacerlo con FileTransfer, pero no me deja añadir un body y solo puedo enviar las imágenes una a una, y no encuentro otra manera para hacerlo.
Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Está bien que subas las imágenes una a una. No veo mal separar los endpoints de las fotos del endpoint donde envías la otra data. De hecho, hacerlo con el `FileTransfer` es mejor para la experiencia de usuario, gracias al método `onProgress`, en el cual podrás mostrarle al usuario el progreso de subida de sus fotos.

Comment: El problema es que tengo que enviar una incidencia, que constará de título, descripción... y de una serie de fotos, entonces lo suyo sería enviarlo todo y que el servidor se encargue de asignarle a la incidencia un id, y guardar las fotos con la id de la incidencia.

Comment: No veo el inconveniente que te impida hacerlo de la otra forma. Subes las fotos, las escribes en el servidor, las guarda en la tabla asignando el `id` de incidencia y se devuelve dicho `id`. Segundo, se envía el resto del payload junto con el `id`.